# ruby cannot load file when run from LaunchControl?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, launchd

I have a ruby file that runs files directly in command line via:

```
ruby /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_ruby/myapp/main.rb
```

When I try to schedule this using LaunchControl on Mac however (using the same command line call) I get the following error?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_ruby/myapp/main.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

This is noting the first lines of my main.rb file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'
```

Any ideas why?  (i.e. why it would run fine when I open a Terminal session, then use the same command line to run it, but when I try to schedule in LaunchControl I get the error)

Comment: Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage your ruby installations? If you type `which ruby` in a terminal where the script works, what is the path to the ruby executable?

Comment: I get this "$ which ruby
/Users/Greg/.rbenv/shims/ruby" - does this help?   Note I posted the fix or workaround (not sure which one) as the answer.  Not sure if this assists in helping understand why the script worked via terminal but not via LaunchControl

Comment: So the ruby, and likely gems as well is under a directory belonging to your user.  but unless launch-control runs in the same user context, it likely has no access to stuff under your user's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I managed to find a post/lead that ended up working.  The following line added to the beginning of my ruby script made things work:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
```

(not sure if one would view this as the root cause fix, c.f. workaround)

Comment: given the error you had, it seems strange that this would have fixed the problem

Comment: I agree with Chuck van der Linden. I would have proposed changing the top line of your file from `#!/usr/bin/ruby` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. The first of your script is telling it to use the system version of ruby. Changing `ruby` to `env ruby` lets the script use the ruby available in the current environment. There may or may not be other changes that should be made to allow this to behave gracefully.